# Console/Terminal Widget for Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, console, widget, terminal

Anyone know of any widget in Qt4 that acts as a terminal/console? Open-source would be good.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found some decent [source code here](http://code.google.com/p/qterminalwidget). Very basic functionality, but I've been adding to it some and I think it has promise to do what I need it to.

NOTE: I have only tested this code in Win32.

Here is a link to [my new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996343/qt-console-widget-writing-arrow-keys-tabs-to-stdin) concerning this code.

Comment: I'd really like a read-only console, but one that supports the \r command so CLI progress bars would work. I was going to roll my own, but then I found this. Would this work?

Comment: Yes. See https://code.google.com/p/qterminalwidget/source/browse/trunk/qconsolewidget.cpp#45

Answer (score 5):

[QConsole](http://qconsole.sourceforge.net/) used to do something like that. (Not sure the project is active anymore, but you might want to have a look).

Comment: This looks more like a python command prompt, not really a bash or MS-DOS terminal. Thanks though.

Comment: Hmm okay. Indeed we looked at it some years ago for the QPyConsole it contains. I assumed the base QConsole could be of use.

Comment: Sadly QConsole is abstract in their implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Qt6, you can use the [QLightTerminal](https://github.com/ChargeIn/QLightTerminal).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Qt5 now, there's the [QTermWidget](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget) widget from the LXQt project.

Comment: see also the [gnu octave fork of libqterminal](https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave/tree/default/libgui/qterminal/libqterminal) with windows support