# no console or terminal widget for Qt ?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm interested in embedding a really simple console for a scripting language inside my GUI ( so it's a widget that is supposed to communicate with the interpreter of the language too ), I browsed the available widgets and the available constructs in Qt but I can't seem to find a real solution that will work out well in my case.

Can you confirm that there is no such widget, at least at the present with Qt 5.2.0 ?

Comment: Copied for @FlorianP 's , his comment:
Since I had a similar Problem a while ago and couldn't really make it work.

As stated by ypnos there is still no Qt terminal widget out of the box. But the [QTermWidget](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget) by lxqt might be the best currently available for Qt5.

The main problem I had with it, was that you cannot directly port it to Qt6, so I had to write my own Qt Terminal widget based on the suckless simple terminal. [QLightTerminal](https://github.com/ChargeIn/QLightTerminal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such widget is not part of Qt 5.2.0.

See this question for alternatives: [Console/Terminal Widget for Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961312/console-terminal-widget-for-qt)