# How to emulate a shell-like scripting environment with QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, shell, qtextedit, qtscript

### [Goal]

A simple shell prompt with `QTextEdit`, or any other appropriate Qt ways.

(Using `QScriptEngine` as an ECMA script interpreter is assumed)

---

### [Example]

*MATLAB*

[image]

*Python*

[image]

In a shell prompt, the command line part is editable while the other parts are not.
For MATLAB, only the line after the last `>>` is editable; for Python shell, only the line after the last `>>>` is editable.

---

### [Workaround]

This is the first idea appear in my mind:

[image]

Using `QTextEdit` as read-only and `QLineEdit` as a command entry.
For the purpose of pure functionality, it's acceptable, but not good enough.

### [Question]

Actually the same question could be found here: [*Implementing a GUI Shell in qt*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945926/implementing-a-gui-shell-in-qt), and the accepted answer is just the same as this workaround. Just like I said, the workaround is not good enough. I am wondering if it's possible to emulate a shell prompt with Qt? Currently, `QTextEdit` seems to be the best class to start.

Any ideas are welcome. Codes are welcome too but not needed, all I need are just some hints and directions.

Comment: Also: [Console/Terminal Widget for Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961312/console-terminal-widget-for-qt).

Comment: Thanks @lpapp. I didn't looking for open-source projects at first. Now there's plenty of examples for my reference, I'll delete this question asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [QConsole](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qconsole/files/) which is a custom widget that implements a basic console and inherits from `QTextEdit`.